# How do I parse CSV in PERL that has quotes in a field?

Tags: perl, csv

My data has quotes in it, the names of properties in addresses are quoted. e.g.

```
"21JAN1984:00:00:00","M",""Millfield""," "
```

PERL Text::CSV dies at this point with an error

```
CSV_PP ERROR: 2025 - EIQ - Loose unescaped escape
```

This looks to me like valid CSV, as is a field, "James said "nice". ".

An abbreviated version of the code used is:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
  binary => 1,
  auto_diag => 1,
  eol => "\n",
  always_quote => 1
}) or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();

open my $fh, '<',  $ARGV[0] or die $!;
while (my $person = $csv->getline_hr($fh)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Addressing the revised question

```
"21JAN1984:00:00:00","M",""Millfield""," "
```

If you want a double quote before `Millfield` and another after it, the correct CSV format is:

```
"21JAN1984:00:00:00","M","""Millfield"""," "
```

As written, the CSV data is broken.  Or, at any rate, it is not the 'standard' format. You can find a standard specification for CSV as [RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180).  This is not identical to Microsoft's specification; the RFC itself identifies that Excel doesn't use precisely this format.

Since you're using Perl's [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) module, you should read its specification.  Note that the **`allow_loose_quotes`** attribute describes input exactly like what you're trying to deal with.  It is one of the many attributes you can use to configure the behaviour of `Text::CSV` in its `new` method.

#### Addressing the original question

What was shown in the original version of the question was horribly ill-formed CSV.

```
21JAN1984:00:00:00","M",""Millfield""," "
```

The double quote after the `00` has no place in the format.  At best, you have to treat it as a regular character at the end of a field delimited by the comma that follows.  The `"M"` is non-controversial.  The `""Millfield""` is malformed; if a string starts with a double quote, it ends at the next double quote unless that is itself followed by another double quote, so the second double quote is erroneous.  If a field starts with a double quote, it should be enclosed by double quotes.  The best you can do is assume that the field is `Millfield""` and stops at the comma, but it is erroneous by any normal rules.  Under those error-recovery rules, the `" "` at the end is non-controversial.

To be reasonably well-formed and to contain `"Millfield"` as a value, you'd need one of these:

```
"21JAN1984:00:00:00","M","""Millfield"""," "
21JAN1984:00:00:00,"M","""Millfield"""," "
21JAN1984:00:00:00,M,"""Millfield"""," "
21JAN1984:00:00:00,M,"""Millfield""",
```

The last of those lines has a trailing blank.

Alternatively, if `Millfield` should not be surrounded by double quotes when extracted, then all the double quotes are superfluous, though any field could be surrounded by a single pair of double quotes.

Comment: Sorry - I missed the leading quote. The date should have a leading quote character.  It is the quotes around "Millfield" that are messing up the parser.

Comment: We can only answer the question you ask; we can't answer the question you meant to ask.  The quotes around Millfield are bogus, as I explained.  You need 3 double quotes at the start to get a single appearance of a double quote in the extracted value.  Anything else is wrong.

Comment: I'll rename the question to be 'quotes in the field'. The question is about the quoted place name. The content of the field is "Millfield" - quoted and that is how 'whatever it is' exported it ,""Millfield"",

Comment: So it answers the question. The definition of CSV used in PERL is not the definition of the exporting tool. Meaning that I need to pre-fangle the data i.e. add a quote for every infield quote perl -p -e 's/(?<=[^,])"(?=[^,])(?!$)/""/g' or play with some other tool. It seems as though adding 2 quotes for every quote doesn't quite do it ,"""Lekamvasa",  fails. But it gets past the ones with paired quotes as in the example in the question.

Comment: There are a lot of variants on CSV format (and that's before we get to using characters other than commas as the field separators).  You can usually fettle the comprehensive tools like Perl's Text::CSV and Python's CSV module into doing what you need, but there's always a chance that the program generating your data isn't handled yet.  If it is a widely used program that's generating the data, you might be able to report the problem to the authors of the modules — but only after you're fairly sure that none of the configuration options deals with your data, either singly or in combination.

Comment: If the program is not widely used, the best bet is to persuade those who did write it to produce a more orthodox format, or provide code to read what they do produce.

Comment: Sorry - I think the data in Lekamvasa is  ,""Lekamvasa", Bamunupola, Batugoda", i.e. quote followed by comma. Go figure.

Comment: allow_loose_quotes did it. I applied this but didn't read the message properly (loose escape found).  Used  allow_loose_escapes => 1 and all records processed. I also tried php - it uses the 'loose' algorithm. Both turn the "Lekamvasa eg into 3 columns - as does openoffice. 3rd tech - groovy with opencsv. Found a field "K\" which meant that everything after was a single record.